# How do you pass in an array from the main method to another method in java?

Tags: java

I have an array of Person in my main method, and I have to pass in that array to PlayGame() method in the class Game. How do you do that?

```
public class RollOff {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        int numPeople;
        int a;


        System.out.println("How many people will play the game?");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = br.readLine();
        numPeople = Integer.parseInt(s);

        if ((numPeople >= 2) && (numPeople <= 10)) {
            Person[] p = new Person[numPeople];
            for (a = 0; a < numPeople; a++) {
                p[0] = new Person(a);
            }

        }

    }
}

public class Game extends RollOff{
    int numPeople;
    int a;


    void PlayGame() {

  }

}
```

Comment: Small comments: a)Don't forget change p[0]=new Person(a); to  p[a]=new Person(a); b)In java naming rules, you have to name methods with first small letter: playGame()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parameters to do that:

```
void playGame(Person[] p){
    ...
}
```

Now simply call

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
    game.playGame(p);
}
```

Because playGame is not a static method, you'll either need to make it static and call `Game.playGame(p)` or you'll need to create an instance of Game: `Game game = new Game()` followed by a call of `game`, as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void play(Person[] person) {

// code
}

// The call
play(person);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a Person array parameter to the PlayGame

```
 void playGame(Person[] personArray){//logic of the method}
```

Then all you have to do is call the playGame method from the main method by creating a new instance of the class Game

```
Game game = new Game();
game.PlayGame(p);
```

here "p" is your persons array.

Answer (score 0):

The main class should create an instance of Game, and pass the array of players to the constructor:

```
Game game = new Game(p);
game.playGame();
```

The Game class should thus have the following field and constructor:

```
private Person[] players;

public Game(Person[] players) {
    this.players = players;
}
```

Note that methods should start with a lower-case letter to follow Java naming conventions, and that your loop has a bug: it always sets the first element of the array instead of initializing every element.

Finally, give meaningful names to variables: `players` is much more readable than `p`.